# I created a conda environment using a yml file but it does not show up as an environment

Tags: python, conda

I created a conda environment using the code below from this yml file.

```
conda env create -f conda_env_torch_zoo.yml
```

I can activate and deactivate this environment but when I run the following command it does not show up as an existing environment.

```
conda env list
```

I am trying to remove this environment but none of the following commands work.

```
conda remove -n envname --all
```

Error: `EnvironmentLocationNotFound: Not a conda environment: ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\torch_zoo`

```
conda remove -p [path] --all
```

Error: `EnvironmentLocationNotFound: Not a conda environment: ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\torch_zoo`

Moreover, although I install the `omegaconf` using this yml file I get this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'omegaconf'`

The yml file:

```
name: torch_zoo
channels:
  - pytorch
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=main
  - antlr-python-runtime=4.9.3=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - intel-openmp=2020.2=254
  - mkl=2020.2=256
  - olefile=0.46=py_0
  - pip=20.2.2=py38_0
  - pycparser=2.21=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pysoundfile=0.10.3.post1=pyhd3deb0d_0
  - python_abi=3.8=1_cp38
  - resampy=0.2.2=py_0
  - setuptools=49.6.0=py38_0
  - six=1.15.0=py_0
  - torchaudio=0.7.2=py38
  - torchvision=0.8.2=py38_cu110
  - tqdm=4.49.0=py_0
  - typing_extensions=4.0.1=pyha770c72_0
  - wheel=0.35.1=py_0
  - pip:
    - opencv-python==4.4.0.44
    - yaml==0.2.5=h516909a_0
    - libgcc-ng==9.1.0=hdf63c60_0
    - scipy==1.5.2=py38h0b6359f_0
    - openssl==1.1.1l=h7f8727e_0
    - ld_impl_linux-64==2.33.1=h53a641e_7
    - libogg==1.3.2=h516909a_1002
    - libuv==1.40.0=h7b6447c_0
    - python==3.8.5=h7579374_1
    - lz4-c==1.9.2=he6710b0_1
    - zlib==1.2.11=h7b6447c_3
    - numpy-base==1.19.1=py38hfa32c7d_0
    - sqlite==3.33.0=h62c20be_0
    - libllvm10==10.0.1=he513fc3_3
    - libiconv==1.16=h516909a_0
    - mkl-service==2.3.0=py38he904b0f_0
    - gnutls==3.6.13=h79a8f9a_0
    - ffmpeg==4.3.1=h167e202_0
    - libedit==3.1.20191231=h14c3975_1
    - openh264==2.1.1=h8b12597_0
    - llvmlite==0.36.0=py38h612dafd_4
    - x264==1!152.20180806=h14c3975_0
    - ninja==1.10.1=py38hfd86e86_0
    - numpy==1.19.1=py38hbc911f0_0
    - libtiff==4.1.0=h2733197_1
    - cudatoolkit==11.0.221=h6bb024c_0
    - pyyaml==5.3.1=py38h8df0ef7_1
    - libvorbis==1.3.7=he1b5a44_0
    - mkl_random==1.1.1=py38h0573a6f_0
    - numba==0.53.1=py38ha9443f7_0
    - omegaconf==2.1.1=py38h578d9bd_1
    - ncurses==6.2=he6710b0_1
    - gmp==6.2.0=he1b5a44_2
    - libpng==1.6.37=hbc83047_0
    - pytorch==1.7.1=py3.8_cuda11.0.221_cudnn8.0.5_0
    - av==8.0.2=py38he20a9df_1
    - tk==8.6.10=hbc83047_0
    - libffi==3.3=he6710b0_2
    - libgfortran-ng==7.3.0=hdf63c60_0
    - jpeg==9b=h024ee3a_2
    - pillow==7.2.0=py38hb39fc2d_0
    - certifi==2021.10.8=py38h578d9bd_1
    - bzip2==1.0.8=h516909a_3
    - lame==3.100=h14c3975_1001
    - xz==5.2.5=h7b6447c_0
    - tbb==2020.2=hc9558a2_0
    - libsndfile==1.0.29=he1b5a44_0
    - nettle==3.4.1=h1bed415_1002
    - ca-certificates==2021.10.26=h06a4308_2
    - cffi==1.14.6=py38h400218f_0
    - freetype==2.10.2=h5ab3b9f_0
    - mkl_fft==1.2.0=py38h23d657b_0
    - libflac==1.3.3=he1b5a44_0
    - readline==8.0=h7b6447c_0
    - zstd==1.4.5=h9ceee32_0
    - lcms2==2.11=h396b838_0
    - gettext==0.19.8.1=h5e8e0c9_1
    - libstdcxx-ng==9.1.0=hdf63c60_0
```